# Not an answer. Forum style extension to parent. Info already moved to parent

Tags: discussion, review, flags

I was reviewing flag queue and just saw a new type of flag. Below is the image,

> [image]

Generally any user flag a post as NAA it looks like the one in blue free handed circle, but what is that red free handed circle one flag indicates ?

**Edit :** The [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3319281/996493) is just handled(deleted) by a moderator while I was posting this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was a Custom flag.  The flagger chose the "custom" option, and typed in the description you circled in red.

All other things being equal, it is better to flag with an explanation of why you are flagging than it is to flag as "not an answer," unless it is crystal-clear that it really is "not an answer."

Comment: First I thought the same that it is custom flag, but how can I view a custom flag ? I am normal 10K user.

Comment: Isn't that what you just did?  In fact, you even took a picture of it, drew a couple of free-hand circles on it, and posted it here.

Comment: Yes, but Custom flags directly goes to moderator's flag queue, am I Correct ?

Comment: Certain custom flags are identified by the system as being actionable by 10k users, @Lucifer, so presumably this was one of those cases.

Comment: @TimStone ok fine, as this happened with me first time, I was surprised, that how come custom flags are coming in my flag queue.

Comment: It's entirely possible that this is part of SE's effort to push more of the moderator work into the 10K queue.  Close votes don't even show up in the diamond moderator queue anymore.